# Select Duplicate SKU's and put corresponding prices into new adjacent columns

Tags: sql

I have the following sql table - with duplicate SKU's - each with differing prices which represent bulk buy discounts:

| SKU | Price |
| --- | --- |
| SKU1 | $10.00 |
| SKU2 | $12.00 |
| SKU2 | $9.00 |
| SKU1 | $10.50 |
| SKU2 | $11.20 |

How can I use a SQL select statement to get the following output in the table below? Unique SKU's with the prices in new columns - prices high to low in the price columns left to right:

| SKU | Price1 | Price2 | Price3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SKU1 | $10.50 | $10.00 |  |
| SKU2 | $12.00 | $11.20 | $9.00 |

My real-world data is for InCatalogue software which I use to bulk update prices in our printed catalogue in Adobe InDesign. The duplicate SKUs with differing prices represent bulk buy discounts. The InCatalogue software uses the identifier (SKU) to update tagged prices/text with the data from whichever column you specify it should look for (Price1, Price2 or Price3).

There is not always the same number of duplicate SKU's - e.g. Some SKU's don't have any bulk buy discounts, hence there would only be a price in column "Price1". Also, my real data actually has up to 4 duplicate SKU's, and I also have to add GST/VAT inclusive prices into additional columns  - however, this is simple and would/could be a simple table update after this transforming of data is done - unless this can simply be calculated at the same time? (Resulting in Price1 exGST, Price1 incGST, Price2 exGST, Price2 incGST etc)

Comment: While this is possible in SQL, a programming language and a mere loop is better suited for this task. Do this in your app, not in SQL.

Comment: You can do this easily with sql, but you are missing the criteria to determine which price belongs in which column, you will need another column to order by such as a date or other value to give each sku/price an ordinal position.

Comment: @sTTu - the criteria for determining which price goes in which column is most expensive to the left-most column through to least expensive to the rightmost column. Im guessing you might be able to do it with some sort of query that uses order by price and then select 1st, 2nd, 3rd, and 4th into the respective columns - however, I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the maximum number of prices, you can use `row_number()` and conditional aggregation:

```
select sku,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then price end) as price_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then price end) as price_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then price end) as price_3
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by sku order by price) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by sku;
```

Note:  This puts the prices in ascending order.  It is not clear what ordering you might actually want, if any.

Comment: Thank you @Gordon Linoff ! That works perfectly as I know that I have a maximum of 4 prices per sku. Hence I modified to add the extra column and order price by desc so that the higher prices are at the beginning.